# Can Ubuntu 22.04 LTS run on wsl

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was just wondering if Ubuntu 22.04 LTS can run on WSL rather than install a VM or native installation.

Comment: Please clarify your details; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is currently at 22.04.2, with only up to 22.04.5 actually scheduled... Do you mean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for example (*it's currently at 20.04.6 for example*).

Comment: Regardless of the above; I'd consider WSL special in a way that requires a rework of a "standard Ubuntu installation media" to make it available (usable) for WSL. So the answer is most likely "no". To bypass that; use e.g. a VM or a "dual boot" install, both of which will behave as a pure Ubuntu.

Comment: wsl --list --online will output the list of possible install candidates.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  See the duplicate question for some details, but yes, you can either install Ubuntu 22.04 from the Microsoft Store or upgrade an existing 20.04 (or interim) Ubuntu distribution on WSL2 to 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search pretty much answers your question. Within the top 5 results, I found this [guide](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux).

I can confirm that once you have enabled WSL on your machine you can install Ubuntu 22.04 from the Microsoft Store.

It is worth pointing out though that under the hood WSL is just a VM installed in Hyper-V with a good amount of integration into the Host OS, but understand that you are actually installing the Hyper-V role on your machine and essentially turning your host OS into a VM as well, with all the implications attached to that.